# Convert time represented as String containing timezone names ('z') to UTC time

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, utc, jodatime

I want to convert Strings like `"20000603163334 GST"` or `"20000603163334 -0300"` to UTC time. The problem is that time zones in my strings can be 'general time zones', I mean they can be strings as CET, GST etc. etc. And I don't know how to convert these ones.

Because of these string time zones I can not use Joda Time's `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddhhmmss z").withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);`, because according to the documentation:  ["Time zone names ('z') cannot be parsed"](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html).

So, one question I have is if you know a method to go around this limitation in Joda Time? I would prefer to use Joda Time, if possible, instead of the standard Java API.

Another in which I thought I can solve this problem with time zone's names is to use the Java's `SimpleDateFormat`.
So I make something like:

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss z");
//f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
f.setCalendar(new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")));
Date time = f.parse("20000603163334 GST");
```

The `SimpleDateFormat` parses the `String` (I don't care here about the problem that there are multiple time zones with the same name - what this class parses it's good for me).

The problem is that I don't know how to convert it from here to UTC. How can I do this?

The fact that I set the `f's` time zone to UTC (in both the two ways from above) doesn't help. I hope someone can help me fix this, I read a lot of questions and answers on this theme here, on stackoverflow, but I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but be careful with that format string. Lowercase "hh" is for parsing half-day hours only (0-12). Most people would want to use "yyyyMMddHHmmss" (uppercase "HH"). Joda's javadocs have a handy list: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found two solutions to your problem.  The first was to set the default time zone to UTC:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

I'm not sure what other side effect this might have.

The second solution I found was to use a different SimpleDateFormat for output.

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss z");
f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date time = f.parse("20000603163334 GST");
System.out.println(time);
System.out.println("(yyyyMMddhhmmss z):  " + f.format(time));
    
SimpleDateFormat utc = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss z");
utc.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    
System.out.println("(yyyyMMddhhmmss z):  " + utc.format(time));
```

Using two SimpleDateFormat objects allowed the output to be put in UTC Time.  Here is the output from running this code:

> Sat Jun 03 08:33:34 EDT 2000
>
> (yyyyMMddhhmmss z):  20000603043334 GST
>
> (yyyyMMddhhmmss z):  20000603123334 UTC

Here may be the reason why Joda does not support 3 letter zone ids.  This is from the TimeZone ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html ) JavaDoc.  As far as Joda goes, I didn't see a workaround, but I'm not very familiar with that library.

> Three-letter time zone IDs For
> compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some
> other three-letter time zone IDs (such
> as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are also
> supported. However, their use is
> deprecated because the same
> abbreviation is often used for
> multiple time zones (for example,
> "CST" could be U.S. "Central Standard
> Time" and "China Standard Time"), and
> the Java platform can then only
> recognize one of them.

Comment: Thanks. I used the second solution you suggested.

Comment: +1 for the last point about time zone abbreviations.  There is a list of them [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/).  Also, many abbreviations are not standardized. For example, you may see either `HAST` or `HST` in Hawaii.  Best to avoid using them altogether.